# how to get GH_TOKEN from gitlab project

Tags: git, gitlab, electron, electron-builder

I want to assign GH_TOKEN in the env variable to implement auto update feature in the electron application. 

 But i am unable to find the GH_TOKEN in the gitlab repository,

Help with implementing auto update feature using private gitlab repository.

Answer (score 1):

from git lab documentation,

- Log in to your GitLab account.
- Go to your Profile settings.
- Go to access tokens. Choose a name and optionally an expiry date for the
  token.
- Choose the desired scopes.
- Click on Create personal access
  token.
- Save the personal access token somewhere safe.
- Once you leave
  or refresh the page, you won't be able to access it again.

Here is the [link.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html)